# Description of PostScript internal error handler procedures

Tags: postscript

I don't know how the title of this question should be...

I'm working on an interpreter, currently I was looking at error handling. I've seen that there is an $error and errordict dictionary which are stored in systemdict.

The PLRM contains information on which errors may occur and a few steps to handle them. However when I execute this command in ghostscript:

```
errordict /stackoverflow get ==
```

I receive this information:

> {/stackoverflow {1 --.instopped-- {null --eq-- {--pop-- --pop--
>   --stop--} --if--} --if-- (I) false --.setdebug-- $error /.inerror --get-- 1 --.instopped-- {--pop--} {--pop-- true} --ifelse-- {.unstoppederrorhandler} --if-- $error /globalmode --.currentglobal--
>   false --.setglobal-- --put-- $error /.inerror true --put-- $error
>   /newerror true --put-- $error --exch-- /errorname --exch-- --put--
>   $error --exch-- /command --exch-- --put-- $error /errorinfo --known--
>   --not-- {$error /errorinfo null --put--} --if-- $error /recordstacks --get-- $error /errorname --get-- /VMerror --ne-- --and-- {--count-- --array-- --astore-- --dup-- $error /ostack 4 -1 --roll-- --countexecstack-- --array-- --execstack-- --dup-- --length-- 2 --sub-- 0 --exch-- --getinterval-- $error /estack 3 -1 --roll-- --countdictstack-- --array-- --dictstack-- $error /dstack 3 -1 --roll-- --put-- --put-- --put-- --aload-- --pop--} {$error /dstack --.undef-- $error /estack --.undef-- $error /ostack --.undef--} --ifelse-- $error /position --currentfile-- --status-- {--currentfile-- {--fileposition--} .internalstopped {--pop-- null}
>   --if--} {$error /command --get-- --dup-- --type-- /filetype --eq-- {{--fileposition--} .internalstopped {--pop-- null} --if--} {--pop--
>   null} --ifelse--} --ifelse-- --put-- $error /globalmode --get-- $error
>   /.nosetlocal --get-- --and-- --.setglobal-- $error /.inerror false
>   --put-- --stop--} --exec--}

And this seems to be a packedarray:

```
errordict /stackoverflow get type pstack
```

result:

> packedarraytype

Now where do I find this kind of information (which manual?)? Where are these procedures described so that I can implement them.

It is not only for errors, but other operators also seem to have a packedarray (procedure) as the value, but I can't find the implementation of this procedures in the PLRM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will become more clear once you get the book *Inside Postscript*, but I can summarize somewhat.

It's hard to see just from the dump above, but if you dump several error handlers the same way, it would become obvious that the big procedure body in the middle is the same for all the handlers, and all handlers follow the same pattern of passing the error name to this procedure (with one exception for the `timeout` error). And you'd actually implement the above like this:

```
errordict /stackunderflow {
    /stackunderflow //signalerror exec
} put
```

Where `signalerror` implements the common code. For the `timeout` error (if you choose to implement that one), there is no *command* to be placed on the stack, so its `errordict` procedure is slightly different.

```
errordict /timeout {
    /timeout /timeout //signalerror exec
} bind put
```

`signalerror` (or `.error` is the name described in the book) takes snapshots of all the stacks and saves them in the `$error` dictionary.

So the sequence for an error is usually:

1. error is triggered by looking up the error name in `errordict` and executing this procedure.
2. the `errordict` procedure calls `signalerror`, passing it the error name.
3. `signalerror` takes snapshots of the stacks, saving the snapshots in `$error`, and then calls `stop`.
4. `stop` pops the exec stack until the nearest enclosing *stopped context* established by the `stopped` operator.
5. if the program has not established its own *stopped context* to catch the error, it will be caught by an outer-level `stopped { handleerror } if` which was called by the startup code to bracket the whole user program.
6. `handleerror` uses the information in `$error` to print an error report.

BTW, you can implement `packedarray` as *read-only* arrays. They were needed in the earliest implementations on memory-constrained printers, but I found it too complicated to design a more compact representation of objects. Behaviorally, the only difference from a regular array is that packed arrays must be *read-only*.

Comment: Just a side-comment, Ghostscript is supplied as source, including all its PostScript machinery. If you really want to know what GS is doing you'd be better off reading the source PostScript (some of which even has comments) than trying to figure out what's going on by poking the interpreter directly. But bear in mind that there is more than one way to solve a problem, GS is not s definitive reference.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the PLRM as much as possible but not everything is described (e.g. where is signalerror?) I only try to use GhostScript to verify my result if it has the same output.

Comment: ps. are you guys on Skype?

Comment: I'm not. Technology-wise, I'm still stuck in the 80s.

Comment: @juFo As Ken says, you can look at the gs source. It looks like most of the error handling is [here](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/ghostscript/Resource/Init/gs_init.ps.in?root=ghostscript&view=markup). Or you can look at [my interpreter](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/xpost/blob/master/data/err.ps).

Comment: @luserdroog your errorhandling (.error or signalerror) is done with a postscript procedure itself. Would it be ok to code a function CopyDataToError() in the interpreter myself and handle it manually instead of executing a postscript interpreter?

Comment: Yes. It can be internal code. It depends on how much of the standard features you need. Programs like my debugger need all of the standard error-trapping hooks, but a document or graphics code may not need it all, or not at first. ... With xpost I wrote a C function as an internal handler. As I built more of the ps part, the C function became a backup handler. Eventually when the ps part worked well, I removed the backup (with fingers crossed!).

Comment: I've written more about [Error Handling here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/postscript/6199/error-handling#t=201704200010214676256)

Comment: @luserdroog When trying to access your resource I get: "We have shut down
Stack Overflow Documentation." - The fate of all URLs it seems 8-(

Comment: @U.Windl that material is now available [here](https://riptutorial.com/postscript) and also [here](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.postscript/c/WOX5SWug5R8/m/w3SL_uPEAQAJ). Sorry for the inconvenience.